# Permission denied error while trying to save image inside Django views

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save an image that I'm scraping from IMDB(using bs4) but I'm getting this error:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/media/Django-Unchained.webp'
```

My code was working fine and I could save the images inside the media directory until I changed some other parts of my code which are completely unrelatable to saving image objects or permissions.

When I restarted the server I suddenly faced this error.

Why would such a thing happen?

Thanks in advance for your ideas on solving this.

Comment: Obviously, the parts you changed actually *did* have something to do with saving image objects and permissions. What were those changes?

Comment: There are really only two possibilities.  Either the file already exists and is marked read-only, or you do not have permission to write to that directory.

Comment: I only added this function : 
`def to_url(name):
        name = name.replace(' ', '-')
        name = name.lower()
        return name`
and also commented some unnecessary scraping data

Answer (score 0):

This is coming from OS as you can’t write on / so fix your ‘MEDIA_ROOT’ attribute in the settings.py

Comment: `MEDIA_URL = '/media/'      
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')`    this is how I defined media root, and it was working fine

Comment: Make sure that your saving to MEDIA_ROOT not MEDIA_URL

Comment: What is the difference?  `img.save('/media/' + img_title + '.webp')` this is how I'm saving it.

Comment: Because  /media is a folder under OS  root not under your webapp, use `img.save(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'/' +img.title+'.webp')